# View multiple browsed images with unique ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After searching in stackoverflow, finally I found a code that can browse multiple images and preview them one-by one. However, when I inspected the element in the browser, all the id for each image is same.

So, I hope anyone can help me how to modify this code so that each image which is browsed has its own unique id.

[Here is the fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/ekzfz9ck/)

And

Here is the html form:

```
<input id="imgInput" type="file"  name="file[]" multiple style="display:none;"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="$('#imgInput').click();" value="Choose File" />
     <output id="result" ></output>

<div style="margin-top:150px;" id="uploadedcontent"></div>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
         var ftype = new Array();

    $("#imgInput").change(function () {
        readURL(this);

    });
    function readURL(input) {
        var files = input.files;
        var output = document.getElementById("result");
        var count = 0;
         var count1 = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            var divid = 'div_' + i;
            var spanid = 'span_' + i;
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                var picFile = event.target;
                var picnames = files[count].name;
                var mimetypes = picFile.result.split(',');
                var mimetype1 = mimetypes[0];
                var mimetype = mimetype1.split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
                count++;

                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + count);
                div.setAttribute('class', 'divclass');
                if (mimetype.match('image')) {
                    div.innerHTML = "<img id='img_" +  count + "' class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + picnames + "' width='96' height='80' alt='Item Image' style='position:relative;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;' data-valu='" + mimetype + "'/><span class='boxclose' style='cursor:pointer' id='span_" + count + "'>x</span>";

                }

                output.insertBefore(div, null);

            });

            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @downvoters this is a legit questions, think about adding a comment...

Comment: Not guilty of downvoting, but I would recommend putting more code into your actual question, rather than a link. Links break.

Comment: I was going to add the code. And now it is added.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/ekzfz9ck/1/show/ ?

Comment: Tested in Chrome - seems to work. Two unique IDs are generated.

Comment: Dosn't work with me. The two images has the same id which is `1`. I want them to have different ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just needs the count used on the div, added to the img just a tiny change see fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/ekzfz9ck/4/

var ftype = new Array(), count1=0;

```
    $("#imgInput").change(function () {
        readURL(this);

    });
    function readURL(input) {
        var files = input.files;
        var output = document.getElementById("result");
        var count = 0;
         var count1 = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            var divid = 'div_' + i;
            var spanid = 'span_' + i;
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                var picFile = event.target;
                var picnames = files[count].name;
                var mimetypes = picFile.result.split(',');
                var mimetype1 = mimetypes[0];
                var mimetype = mimetype1.split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
                count++;
                count1++;

                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + count);
                div.setAttribute('class', 'divclass');
                if (mimetype.match('image')) {

                    // below we add the id using the count used for the div;
                    div.innerHTML = "<img id='img_" +  count1 + "' class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + picnames + "' width='96' height='80' alt='Item Image' style='position:relative;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;' data-valu='" + mimetype + "'/><span class='boxclose' style='cursor:pointer' id='span_" + count + "'>x</span>";

                }

                output.insertBefore(div, null);

            });

            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
```